# propblem running rtabmap continuesly

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello sir, im trying to run the rtabmap_ros/Tutorial:
RGB-D Hand-Held Mapping With a Kinect, with my kinect xbox, with ros indigo, ubuntu 14,04. My problem is after i run:

```
roslaunch rtabmap_ros rgbd_mapping.launch rtabmap_args:="--delete_db_on_start"
```

i get the rtabmap widow with required output depth image but it don't output the image continuesly, i dont get what is problem.
i was following this link:
http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/HandHeldMapping

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236764/propblem-running-rtabmap-continuesly./) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2016-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

There is an [issue](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/issues/80) with the released `0.11.5` binaries that may cause what you are observing. The bug is that a new map is started each time a red screen happens. You can see it as the graph in 3D View would change color. It should be fixed in `0.11.7`. Latest Indigo and Jade (Kinetic is ok) binaries should be released soon. Until there, you can setup the [shadow-fixed](http://wiki.ros.org/ShadowRepository) repository to get the latest ROS binaries (with `rtabmap_ros` `0.11.7` for Indigo or Jade). The second option is to [build the package from source](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros#build-from-source).

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2016-06-12**:
o... ok. i got it. thanks for help.